# Is there a faster way to compute the running median?

Tags: python, numpy

Is there a built-in function or faster way to compute the following?

```
x = np.array([67, 51, 42, 37, 21, 10, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1])

def half_life_idx(x):
    middle = sum(x) / 2
    for idx, val in enumerate(x):
        middle = middle - val 
        if middle <= 0:         
            break

    return idx

half_life_idx(x)

>> 1
```

In other words, I want to find the index of `x` where the cumulative sum of `x[0:index+1] >= sum(x)/2`.

Comment: The complexity is O(n) so i doubt you can get faster algorithm than this.

Comment: I'm not a downvoter, but I think you could improve the question by providing a better explanation of what you are computing (even though we can, in principle, figure it out from the code, assuming the code is correct).  Saying "... the index of the middle value sum(x)/2 of an array x" doesn't quite match what the code is doing.  For the example you show, `sum(x)/2` is 117.5, and that value does not show up in `x`, so what does it mean to find the index of that value?

Comment: I don't think referring to the median helps.  The median of `x` is 10, which doesn't seem relevant, and "the median of the summed values" isn't clear--the sum is 235, so what does the median of that mean?  My interpretation is that you want the index of first value in the *cumulative* sum of x that equals or exceeds sum(x)/2.  Is that correct?  (By cumulative sum, I mean the array that results from `np.cumsum(x)`.)

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser that is correct, thanks for helping me rephrase :)  I'm running a series of Bernoulli experiments and I want to find the expected value (p is changing with each iteration so can't calculate it analytically). That's what `idx` is supposed to mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine the `cumsum` and `searchsorted` methods to implement a faster version:

```
def half_life_idx_ww(x):
    cs = np.cumsum(x)
    middle = cs[-1]/2
    return cs.searchsorted(middle)
```

For example,

```
In [167]: x = np.array([67, 51, 42, 37, 21, 10, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1])

In [168]: half_life_idx(x), half_life_idx_ww(x)
Out[168]: (1, 1)

In [169]: w = np.random.gamma(1.5, size=200)

In [170]: half_life_idx(w), half_life_idx_ww(w)
Out[170]: (99, 99)
```

Answer (score 2):

An other way of doing this would be with `np.argmax`  see function `f1` of this example :

```
import numpy as np

def f0(x):
    #leermeester's orginal method
    middle = sum(x) / 2
    for idx, val in enumerate(x):
        middle = middle - val 
        if middle <= 0:         
            break
    return idx

def f1(x):
    #my method using argmax
    cs = x.cumsum()
    return np.argmax(cs>cs[-1]/2)

def f2(x):
    #Warren Weckesser's method using searchsorted
    cs = np.cumsum(x)
    middle = cs[-1]/2
    return cs.searchsorted(middle)
```

And here are some benchmarks for each method :

```
print("small run")
x = np.array([67, 51, 42, 37, 21, 10, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1])

%timeit(f0(x))
%timeit(f1(x))
%timeit(f2(x))


print("larger run")
x = np.random.rand(int(1.0E3))

%timeit(f0(x))
%timeit(f1(x))
%timeit(f2(x))

print("very large run")
x = np.random.rand(int(1.0E6))

%timeit(f0(x))
%timeit(f1(x))
%timeit(f2(x))

#a print to make sure all give the same result
print(f0(x),f1(x),f2(x))
```

**Benchmark results**:

```
small run
2.48 µs ± 41.4 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
3.47 µs ± 57.8 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
2.7 µs ± 49.6 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
larger run
184 µs ± 2.59 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
6.2 µs ± 51.6 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
5.01 µs ± 14.4 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
very large run
185 ms ± 1.09 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
3.3 ms ± 230 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
2.64 ms ± 138 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
500260 500260 500260
```

**Conclusions:**  your method is the fastest for very small arrays, but with larger ones it gets much slower than the proposed answers with Warren's solution being consistently 30%ish faster than mine.